# Unit testing multiple providers using Vitest

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest

I am trying to unit test nested providers using Vitest. I want to test that all the providers are getting added and are not mistakenly removed in the future.

Here is my component:

```
//AppProviders.tsx
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import theme from '../themeing/theme';
import i18n from '../languageSetup/i18nConfig';
import { AuthenticationProvider } from './AuthenticationProvider';

const AppProviders: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <I18nextProvider data-testid="I18nextProvider" i18n={i18n}>
      <BrowserRouter data-testid="BrowserRouter">
        <AuthenticationProvider data-testid="AuthenticationProvider">
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme} data-testid="ThemeProvider">
            {children}
          </ThemeProvider>
        </AuthenticationProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
};

export default AppProviders;
```

In the unit test if I mock the providers like this:

```
//first example
    vi.mock('react-i18next', () => ({ I18nextProvider: 'I18nextProvider' }));

//second example
    tried rendering children as well in the mock 

//third example - tried checking if the ProviderComponents has been called once
    expect(I18nextProvider).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
//in second and third example, I need to mock, which doesn't work with child components in place
```

Comment: _Don't_ unit test this. Have a higher-level test (integration/E2E/acceptance/functional) that ensures the client app can start up. (In general, don't mock what you don't own.)